# json render issue using react to generate form field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a static form like this (in test.js file).

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
              <Field
                component={TextField}
                variant="outlined"
                name="remarks"
                placeholder="Please enter remarks."
                label="Remarks"
              />
```

**above approach is working fine**.but now I want to create same thing using json.Mean parse the json and render the form .

here is my logic

```
const getField = function(item) {
    // for (let i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
    const { type } = item;
    console.log(type, "type", TEXTFIELD);
    switch (type) {
      case TEXTFIELD:
        return (
          <Field
            component={TextField}
            multiline
            rows="4"
            variant="outlined"
            name="remarks"
            placeholder="Please enter remarks."
            label="Remarks"
          />
        );
    }
  };
```

but it is not returning any thing why ???

I want to parse json and get the same form . here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-chaplygin-c4k06

```
{RESCHEDULE_FORM.map(i => {
                {
                  getField(i);
                }
              })}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) takes a function as an argument that returns an element
>   for the new mapped array.

But in your case that function is not returning anything. It is just executing another function `getField` inside it. As suggested by G_S, for the expected output you have to return a value from the function passed inside map, like so:

```
{
  RESCHEDULE_FORM.map(i => {
     return getField(i)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use map, dont forget to return a value from it.

```
{RESCHEDULE_FORM.map(i => {
   {
     return getField(i);
   }
 })}
```

or you can just say

```
{RESCHEDULE_FORM.map(i =>  getField(i) )}
```

An arrow function when used without any brackets implies a return. So what ever you returned from getField will be returned.